# Case Statement Syntax - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, case

I'm trying to integrate a really simple check into a trigger with SQL Server 2012. During an INSTEAD OF trigger, I would like to check the following as per this pseudo code:

```
IF Inserted.FloorRef = ('various', 'different', 'strings')
THEN check that Inserted.FloorNumber IS NOT NULL
```

I've declared a bit variable that gets set to 1 if this test is passed or if the else condition is met, so that further code can be run under known conditions. My code is below, but it fails with:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE' (Inserted.FloorRef)
And also;
Must declare the scalar variable "@Passed"

There must be a syntax error or ten, but I'm failing to find out where, what have I got wrong?

```
DECLARE @Passed BIT = 0

CASE Inserted.FloorRef 
    WHEN EXISTS IN ('Floor', 'Level', 'Fl', 'L') THEN --FloorNumber is required
        CASE Inserted.FloorNumber 
            WHEN IS NOT NULL THEN --FloorNumber is given
                @Passed = 1
            ELSE --FloorNumber is required but is missing
                @Passed = 0
        END;
    ELSE --FloorNumber is not required
        @Passed = 1
END;

IF @Passed=1
    BEGIN
```

EDIT: The solution just needed a minor correction to Daniel E's, proposed solution below:

```
SELECT *
    ,CASE WHEN Inserted.FloorRef IN ('Floor', 'Level', 'Fl', 'L') THEN --FloorNumber is required
        CASE
            WHEN Inserted.FloorNumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1 --FloorNumber is given
            ELSE 0 --FloorNumber is required but is missing
        END
    ELSE 1 --FloorNumber is not required
    END [Passed]
FROM Inserted
```

Comment: Why not just have a `CHECK` constraint on the table and forget the trigger?

Comment: `set @passed=CASE...` not `...THEN @passed=...`

Comment: Because the trigger goes on to do check against fields in other tables using subqueries. Could I combine a table level check constraint with an Instead Of trigger...?

Comment: @Daniel E,
That resolved part of the problem, now it is noting incorrect syntax at 'EXISTS IN' ('various', 'different', 'strings'). How do I combine an 'IN' with a 'CASE'?

Comment: If you can give details of the actual constraints that you're seeking to enforce, we may be able to offer suggestions.

Comment: Okay, I will do in a little while. I'm just pursuing Daniel E's suggestion below at the moment, I'll see how that pans out...

Comment: see answer below, `exists` is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

This will tell you each row pass/fail, and you can use those results as you wish.

```
SELECT * 
    ,CASE WHEN Inserted.FloorRef  IN ('Floor', 'Level', 'Fl', 'L') THEN --FloorNumber is required
             CASE WHEN Inserted.FloorNumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1 --FloorNumber is given
               ELSE 0 --FloorNumber is required but is missing                    
               END
     ELSE 1--FloorNumber is not required
     END [Passed]
FROM Inserted
```

Comment: Ah, took my eyes off it and you beat me to it.

Comment: This looks like it will work for my problem, though it's giving a syntax error; any idea why? The problem is with the IS in this line:
WHEN IS NOT NULL THEN 1 --FloorNumber is given

Comment: You can't use a simple case expression for anything other than `=` comparisons. The inner `CASE` needs to be turned into a searched case expression (nothing between `CASE` and the first `WHEN` clause) like the outer one.

Comment: That needs to be `CASE WHEN Inserted.FloorNumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: Thanks gents, I actually realised that myself in the end and then saw your responses. You're spot on, it needed to be a searched case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Inserted is a table you have to treat it like one. There is not from clause. You also have to understand that there may be multiple records in inserted so you can't set a scalar variable, what happens if some records should be passed = 1 and others should be 0. Triggers do not work row-by-row!

I woudl alos as Damien suggested look at a check constraint instead.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, note that the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` pseudo tables in triggers can have multiple rows when multiple rows are inserted / updated / deleted, which you will need to handle.

That said, this will examine the first inserted row and set the @Passed bit.

```
  DECLARE @FloorRef VARCHAR(20);
  DECLARE @FloorNumber  VARCHAR(20);
  DECLARE @Passed BIT = 0;

  SELECT TOP 1 @FloorRef = Inserted.FloorRef, @FloorNumber = Inserted.FloorNumber
  FROM INSERTED;

  SELECT @PASSED = CASE 
      WHEN @FloorRef IN ('Floor', 'Level', 'Fl', 'L') THEN --FloorNumber is required
          CASE
              WHEN @FloorNumber IS NOT NULL THEN --FloorNumber is given
                  1
              ELSE --FloorNumber is required but is missing
                  0
          END
       ELSE --FloorNumber is not required
          1
       END;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6bf5)